# Show that a group of order 7 has no subgroups of order 4.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I can do this with the use of Lagrange's theorem but my professor says its possible without it. I can't find how to go about solving it. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: In a group of order $p$ for a prime $p$, what is the order of any non-identity element?

Comment: The order is p. How does this show no subgroups of order not equal to p are possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, suppose your subgroup is $G=\{1,a,b,c\}$, and your big group is $H=G\cup \{d,e,f\}$.

Now, what can $ad$ be?  Not $1$, since $a^{-1}\in G$ and $d\notin G$.  Not $a$, since $d\neq 1$.  Not $b$ (resp. $c$) since $a^{-1}b\in G$ (resp. $a^{-1}c\in G$).  Also not $d$, since $a\neq 1$.   Hence $ad\in \{e,f\}$.  By similar logic, $bd, cd\in \{e,f\}$.  By the pigeonhole principle, two of these must agree.  Without loss, suppose $ad=e=bd$.  But now $add^{-1}=bdd^{-1}$ so $a=b$, a contradiction.

Comment: Could I also show that since G is prime it is cyclic and so every subgroup of G is cyclic. However there are groups of order 4 that are not cyclic so it can't be the case.

Comment: 1. It's a nontrivial lemma that all groups of prime order are cyclic.  2. Using that lemma forces the order-4 subgroup to be cyclic, but that alone is not a contradiction.

Answer (score 7):

Let $H$ be a hypothetical subgroup of order 4 and suppose $x\notin H$. Then $xH$ cannot be disjoint from $H$ because the group has only 7 elements. Thus there are $a,b\in H$ such that $xa=b$. But then $x=ba^{-1}\notin H$, contradicting the assumption that $H$ is a subgroup.

Comment: You're arguing that $xH$ and $H$ cannot be disjoint *because they share an element*. Every subgroup contains the identity element, so this argument always holds for hypothetical subgroups of order $\lceil ord(G)/2 \rceil$. Therefore your proof shows that there are no subgroups whose order is half of the group order (round up). Is my generalization correct?

Comment: @RobW really half the order rounded down plus one (or larger), to account for groups of even order.

Comment: @RobW it's really the same argument as Lagrange's theorem; two cosets must be disjoint or equal. Then you show they all have the same size. This admits a shorter proof though because the translates cannot possibly be disjoint.

Comment: Sir i didn't get this line "$xH$ cannot be disjoint from $H$ because the group has only 7 elements" please elaborate

Comment: @Akash If $xH$ were disjoint from $H$, $H\cup xH$ would have eight elements.

Answer (score 4):

Let $G$ be a group of order $7$ and $H$ a subgroup of order $4$, say $H=\{e,x,y,z\}$. Take $a \in G-H$. Let us have a look at $ax$. If this element would belong to $H$, then, since $x^{-1} \in H$, we would have $ax \cdot x^{-1}=a \in H$, which is not the case. So $ax \notin H$. Similarly, $ay, az \notin H$. Hence the set $K=\{a,ax,ay,az\}$ is disjoint from $H$. But now we have constructed $8$ elements. We conclude that amongst the elements of $K$, there must be two equals, say for example $a=ax$. This would give $x=e$, a contradiction. Similarly, the equality of any other pair of elements of $K$ would lead to a contradiction.